# How to scale a large bitmap to a squared bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, scale

After I take a photo I want to view it in a square. I follow [this guide](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html), but the bitmap created is rectangular, it creates a scaled image.
My question is: what should I change in that code to create a scaled **squared** image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do this using BitmapFactory.Options.

A simple way to do it (this creates another bitmap so will use up memory) is:

```
    Bitmap output;
    if (bitmap.getWidth() >= bitmap.getHeight())
        output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth() / 2 - bitmap.getHeight() / 2, 0, bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getHeight());
    else
        output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, bitmap.getHeight() / 2 - bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getWidth());
```

Comment: There is another solution: Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(myBitmap,height,width);

Comment: Thanks, I had not seen this method before!